# How do I write a query to join columns from 3 separate tables in the Northwind database

Tags: sql-server

I am working with the Northwind database and trying to write a query that joins 3 separate tables. Here is what I'm trying to do -

1. From the `Order Details` table, I want to get the `OrderID, TotalSales = UnitPrice * Quantity`
2. Join the `EmployeeID` from the `Orders` table
3. Join `Name = FirstName+ ' '+LastName` from the `Employees` table

I am able to write a query to join all 3 tables, however I cannot seem to select the columns calculated columns that I need. Here is the query I'm using to join the 3 tables -

```
select a.*, b.*, c.*
from [Order Details] a 
    inner join Orders b
on a.OrderID = b.OrderID
    left join Employees c
on b.EmployeeID = c.EmployeeID
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select 
  (e.FirstName+ ' '+ e.LastName) as EmployeeName,
  od.OrderID,
  od.ProductID,
  od.UnitPrice,
  od.Quantity,
  (od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) as TotalSales,
  od.Discount
from 
dbo.[Order Details] od
    inner join dbo.Orders as o on od.OrderID = o.OrderID
    inner join dbo.Employees e on o.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. How do I modify this query to sum the TotalSales by Employee?

Comment: Select 
(e.FirstName+ ' '+ e.LastName) as EmployeeName,
 Sum(od.Unit * od.Quantity) as TotalSales
from 
dbo.[Order Details] od
    inner join dbo.Orders as o on od.OrderID = o.OrderID
    inner join dbo.Employees e on o.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID

Group by (e.FirstName+ ' '+ e.LastName)

Answer (score 1):

Using an asterisk as the column list is a bad habit to unlearn. It might be acceptable for development purposes but rarely does any production-level query need all columns. Only select the columns you actually need. In addition, why do you left join? Is EmployeeID nullable? It **is** a foreign key so it must be required if it is not nullable. And last comment - use short but useful (not cryptic) aliases. "a", "b", and "c" give you no clues about the tables involved.

Your join logic (ignoring the outer join) is correct. So your question can be boiled down to "how to include an expression in the select list that refers to other columns"? As an abbreviated and incomplete example:

```
select emp.EmployeeID, ord.OrderID, orddet.ProductID, ordet.UnitPrice, 
       orddet.Quantity, ordet.UnitPrice * orddet.Quantity as xx 
from dbo.[Order Details] as orddet
inner join dbo.Orders as ord
   on orddet.OrderID = ord.OrderID
inner join dbo.Employees as emp
   on ord.EmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID
order by ... ;
```

Notice the changes. First, an actual column list. Adjust for your needs. Next each table is schema-qualified - a best practice. Aliases are short but directly associated with the actual table name. I used "xx" as an alias for the expression that calculates the total for the detail row - adjust for your needs. There is an ORDER BY clause - adjust for your needs. Lastly, the statement has a terminator - another best practice and an eventual requirement.

The name "TotalSales" used in your description is not clear and can be interpreted in different ways. To me it sounds like it represents the total for an order (and not for each detail row). Obviously I did the latter. Given the focus on employee perhaps it refers to total sales for each employee? You might need to aggregate and sum.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips. I'm new to SQL so these tips are very helpful